# +2 for user was removed

Tags: discussion

> +2    2 hours ago     removed     User was removed

I am just curious: is this return the points taken off by a downvote made by a user just removed?

Comment: I guess it is this case: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5122/removal-of-votes-when-a-user-is-removed?rq=1

Comment: This reminds me of the joke about the person with such a negative personality that when he walks into a room people look around and ask, who just left?

Comment: Yeah, MathSE brings this into reality, @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 11):

Yup${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Cool, thank you Alex.